# Changing the property of A object affects the changing the property of B object

Tags: c#, object, memory-management

I have this line of code:

```
SomeClass a = new SomeClass();
SomeClass b = a;
a.price = 15;
b.price = 20;

Console.WriteLine(a.price); // output 20
```

First I create object a, and then object b. To object b I assigned object a. When I initialize property price to those object, as you can see price of object a is 15 and of b is 20. But when you assign 20 to price of object b, in the same time changes would be affected on price of object a. **Why?**

I mean what happens in memory to cause this?

Comment: object b is a reference to object a, a pointer if you know pointers, so if either a or b change the other reflects the change

Comment: @MEYWD: `b` isn't an object at all. It's a *variable*. The value of `b` is the same as the value of `a` - both are references to the same object. It's very important to distinguish between the concepts of variables, references and objects. Changing the value of `a` (to refer to a different object) would *not* do anything to the value of `b`. It's only a change to the object that both of them refer to that's reflected.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are correct, i just wanted to explain it in a simple form, and by object i meant variable.

Comment: @MEYWD: The trouble is that making things "simple" often confuses things :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeClass` is a reference type (declared with class `SomeClass { ... }`).
The `a` and `b` reference the same instance of the class (the one you create with `new SomeClass()`. It means, it points to the same instance (then to the same memory item).

To have the behavior you want you have to use a value type (declared with struct `SomeStruct { ... }`).

Comment: Yes, when I change **class** with **struct** this is not happen. Thanks.

Comment: However, be careful with structs. Because doing `b = a` will duplicate the memory of the `a` to `b` (even calling a method with `a` as parameter will duplictae it). So, don't create big structs.  See [Using structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic difference between `ValueType` and `ReferenceType`.

With ValueType a single space in memory is allocated to store the value.(Ex: int, bool, char are value types).

With ReferenceType an object is created in memory, and then handled through a separate reference—rather like a pointer. This reference is responsible to change the value of the previous object. 
[More here](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspxMore)